# how do i get files to the github server?

Tags: git, github

This question involves github.  It might need to be migrated to another site.

How do I get files to the github server?

I've setup my user.name, user.email, and github.token on the client side

also, I've also translated my SSH key to the server side at github.com.

I verified SSH by using

`ssh -T git@github.com`

SSH is working

According to the directions, you simply stage your files, commit them, and push them.

When working in the Bash Shell I use

```
git push origin master
```

However this gives me the error...

```
![rejected] master->master(non-fast forward)
```

I'm basically following the directions from here

```
http://help.github.com/
```

Setting up Git, and Creating a Git Repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you already have something committed there that's ahead of what you have.

```
git fetch
```

then

```
git log --all --graph # or gitk --all
```

to see what those changes are.

If you want to ignore them and blast the history (not recommended if you are working with others on there) force the push:

```
git push -f
```

or, rebase or merge your changes on top of whatever is on the server:

```
git merge origin/master # assumes you are on the master branch
```

or

```
git rebase origin/master
```

Now you should be able to push:

```
git push origin master # can be just git push if you are tracking
```

Comment: "you already have something committed that is ahead of what you have"...can you elaborate...things worked out.

Comment: yes. that is a warning that by pushing your commit up, you would be erasing some commits on the remote. Take a look at the explanation of how git works wrt history. It's a scheme known as the DAG (directed acyclic graph). Essentially, nothing will be pointing to that commit and it will be lost along with any other commits it has that you don't if you make that branch point to your commit instead.

Answer (score 1):

Create a repository on Github. Follow the instructions from there.